# SUBSTRING with multiple CHARINDEX options in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

A column I'm trying to extract only the last name from has possible combinations like `H.Naude` or `H. Naude` or `H Naude` and I need just the `Naude` part. If I use the `SUBSTRING` method I'm able to get the characters after either the space or the point but how to test for all 3 possibilities? Unfortunately this data comes from an imported entry form so I have no control as to how the data is formatted. Currently I have the following which is only for the space character

```
SUBSTRING(H.PtsNonFemale, CHARINDEX('' '', H.PtsNonFemale) +1, DATALENGTH(H.PtsNonFemale) - CHARINDEX('' '', H.PtsNonFemale) +1 ) AS Female
```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Is that the only possible patterns you are looking for? i.e. ".", " " or ", "?

Comment: Hi Dale, Yes those are the only scenarios I've found in 30+k worth of records over a few years so it's safe to assume so.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Hi @DaleK, apologies, haven't been at my machine for a bit. This is more of a passion & hobby & sometimes a small source of income but not what I do for a living. I'll respond now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data provided covers all use-cases then you can simply test for each case in descending length order of the of the component you want to remove and use the first match (longest) found in the substring.

```
SELECT H.PtsNonFemale
    , SUBSTRING(H.PtsNonFemale, COALESCE(NULLIF(I.A,0)+6,NULLIF(I.B,0)+2,NULLIF(I.C,0)+1,NULLIF(I.D,0)+1), LEN(H.PtsNonFemale)) AS Female
FROM (
    VALUES
    ('H.Naude'), ('H. Naude'), ('H Naude'), ('A. M. Someone')
) H (PtsNonFemale)
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
    (PATINDEX('_. _. %', H.PtsNonFemale), CHARINDEX('. ',H.PtsNonFemale,0), CHARINDEX('.',H.PtsNonFemale,0), CHARINDEX(' ',H.PtsNonFemale,0))
) I (A, B, C, D);
```

Returns:

| PtsNonFemale | Female |
| --- | --- |
| H.Naude | Naude |
| H. Naude | Naude |
| H Naude | Naude |
| A. M. Someone | Someone |

Comment: Well now I contradict myself after trying your solution which works awesomely but I've found last names that have none of those characters & another which has A. M. Someone which returns M. Someone

Comment: Better ensure your question covers **ALL** use-cases. That said, it shouldn't be that hard to adapt this to handle more situatons.

Comment: Thanks @Dale . I'm using this in a dynamic query & I have a WHERE statement which compares the result of Female LIKE parameter. Since Female is unknown in the where do I need to replicate the SUBSTRING & CROSS APPLY with new variables in the WHERE statement. Old Dog learning new tricks here

Comment: If you need to use the `Female` calculated value again add it as another `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: I've learnt something new again thanks to you. Now I've a new technique to play around with. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to tokenize a string of tokens instead of parsing.

SQL Server XQuery allows to that very easily.

No need to call barrage of string functions: `SUBSTRING(), COALESCE(), NULLIF(), LEN(), PATINDEX(), CHARINDEX()`, etc. multiple times.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, PtsNonFemale VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (PtsNonFemale) VALUES
('H.Naude'),
('H. Naude'),
('H Naude'),
('A. M. Someone');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '.';

SELECT t.*
    , c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS Female
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(PtsNonFemale,SPACE(1),@separator), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------+---------+
| ID | PtsNonFemale  | Female  |
+----+---------------+---------+
|  1 | H.Naude       | Naude   |
|  2 | H. Naude      | Naude   |
|  3 | H Naude       | Naude   |
|  4 | A. M. Someone | Someone |
+----+---------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string_split()`:

```
select
  PtsNonFemale,
  (select top 1 value
   from string_split(PtsNonFemale, ' ', 1)
   order by ordinal desc) as Female
from mytable
```

Comment: Hi @Bohemian, Thanks for the response. I'm aware of string_split but it's only from 2016 onwards & I still only have 2014. I'll keep this in mind when we've been able to upgrade